# Minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

If $A$ is a square matrix, which resets the polynomial $P(t) = t^2 + 5t + 1$. then $A$ is invertible matrix ?

How can I approach such an exercise, how can I tell if a matrix is invertible by this rule? is it even true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If $P(A) = A^2+5A+I = 0$, then $I = -A^2-5A = A(-A-5I)$.

Comment: Got it.. can't believe it was that simple.. thanks